# jruby on rails with warbler and tomcat and windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

I tried to deploy an application.war file into webapps/ in the tomcat folder and started up the server. When i try to open `http://localhost:8080/relConnections` it shows on the screen that "something went wrong". I deleted the common index.html in the public folder in usual rails apps and tchanged the root to my home page.

When i see the log file it says the following:

```
"An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass
--- System
jruby 1.6.7"
```

and three or four more excecption saying the same lines gsub nil:NilClass for all of those.

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'jruby-jars', '1.6.7'
gem 'warbler', '1.3.2'
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'

gem 'jruby-openssl', '0.7.5', :platforms => :jruby
gem 'json', '1.6.5', :platforms => [:jruby, :mingw, :mingw_19]
gem 'therubyrhino', :platforms => :jruby

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '1.2.2'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '1.4.0'

gem 'mechanize', '1.0.0'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.0'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end 

gem 'jquery-rails'
group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug-base', '0.10.4'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.4.17.beta8'
  gem 'pry', '0.9.7.4'
end

group :test do
  gem 'turn', '0.8.3', :require => false
  gem 'minitest', '2.11.0'
  gem 'timecop', '0.3.5'
end
gem 'jruby-pageant', '~>1.0.2'

gem 'net-ssh', '~>2.5.2'
```

And here is my warble.rb

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  #commented code
  config.dirs = %w(app config lib log vendor tmp)
  #more commented code
end
```

Let me know if iam missing any gems or anything else here.
Thanks

Comment: I've seen this error before, I think that the problem is in jruby-rack. Try a bundle update and use the latest one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may try to set the jruby version to 1.9. In the warble.rb

```
config.webxml.jruby.compat.version = "1.9"
```